# D3- understanding the calling object for the d3 call() method

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and still learning.
I have ***node*** and ***link*** as variables in d3 that select the respective nodes and links from the given json data format /graph.
I wrote a function to change color of each of the links based on it's ***source*** and ***target*** name.

What I could not understand is that calling this function on the variable ***node*** changes the color of the links too. So does it even matter what object I call this function on ? Does the ***d*** variable change internally from node to link based on what I call the function from?

## Code

```
//How link is defined
var link=svg
.append("g")
.selectAll("line")
.data(graph.links)
.enter()
.append("line")
.attr("stroke-width",function(d){
  return 3
})
.style("stroke","pink")
.text("text",function(d){return d.name});

//How node is defined
var node =svg
.append("g")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r",5)
.attr("fill", function(d){
  return "orange"
})
.attr("stroke","yellow")
;

//link.call(updateState1)
//This works as it should

node.call(updateState1)
// I can't understand why this line works too.

function updateState1() {

    link
      .each(function(d) {
          var colors=["red","green","blue"]
          var num=0;
          if(d.source.name.length>d.target.name.length)
          {
              num=1;
              console.log("Inside 1");
              console.log("Source is ",d.source.name," and target is ",d.target.name);
          }
          else if(d.source.name.length<d.target.name.length)
          {
              num=2;
              console.log("Inside 2");
              console.log("Source is ",d.source.name," and target is ",d.target.name);
          }
          else{
            num=0;
          }
        // your update code here as it was in your example
        d3
        .select(this)
        .style("stroke", function(d){ return colors[num]})
        .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)');
        
  
        
      });

      
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`selection.call`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call) the first parameter of the function is the `selection` calling it. So if you look at:

```
function updateState1() {

    link
      .each(function(d) {
```

You can see that you're explicitly using `link`, which is why the links are getting updated. Instead, if you change it to:

```
function updateState1(selection) {

    selection
      .each(function(d) {
```

It should use the selection from `selection.call` (`node` in the case of `node.call(updateState1)`).

If the function you pass to `selection.call` doesn't take any arguments, it's equivalent to just calling the function itself (i.e. if `fn` doesn't have any parameters `selection.call(fn)` is the same as `fn()`).

Comment: yeah , but then there's no point in calling it from either node or link?

Comment: Yes, from the way that you wrote it, `node.call(updateState1)` should be equivalent to just `updateState()`